# QMAKE: QMAKESPEC has not been set

Tags: qt, qmake

I have recently recompiled Qt so that I can use static instead of shared libraries. But now, when I try to compile my project, I get the following error:

> QMAKESPEC has not been set, so configuration cannot be deduced.

It seems like a common problem and I did do some research before posting. What's puzzling me is that I did set the QMAKESPEC env var. Here is the output of ***printenv QMAKESPEC***

> /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.4.0/mkspecs/linux-g++

Also, here is the output of ***qmake -query QMAKESPEC***

> linux-g++

I have also tried playing around with the values, but it seems that qmake can't see that variable at all... QTDIR is also specified properly.

I have also tried to recompile Qt and reinstall it.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, sorry, I think I know what's the problem. I have been picking up qmake from the old Qt installation that was left in /usr/bin/. I have deleted it now, and going to re-try installing Qt. Hope it will work =)

Answer (score 25):

Just add this to a script before running qmake

```
Unix Bourne shell:

        QMAKESPEC=/usr/local/qt/mkspecs/linux-g++
        PATH=$PATH:/local/qmake/bin
        export QMAKESPEC PATH

Unix C shell:

        setenv QMAKESPEC /usr/local/qt/mkspecs/linux-g++
        setenv PATH $PATH:/local/qmake/bin

Microsoft Windows:

        set QMAKESPEC=c:\qt\mkspecs\win32-msvc
        set PATH=%PATH%;c:\qmake\bin
```

qmake is now installed.

Comment: It works but on my system the right absolute path was `/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++` (took me some time to figure out where that was).

Answer (score 2):

if you are lazy to do extra set-env stuff, do here is a one liner:

```
    qmake -spec c:\qt\mkspecs\win32-msvc myproject.pro
```

same goes for other platforms

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it by installing the libqt4-dev package.

Comment: Unfortunately this answer is irrelevant to the problem the OP had - dealing with custom, static build of Qt rather than the distro one.

Answer (score 1):

From 4.8 on, qmake has a system of persistent information that can be defined using the `-set` option, and consulted using `-query`.

For more detail, consult the [Configuring qmake's Environment](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qmake-environment-reference.html) for qmake 4.8, and [Configuring qmake](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-environment-reference.html) for qmake 5.0.