# Where can I find a source code repository of QMake?

Tags: qt, qmake

I tried to find the repository on [Qt Project Git Repository Browser](http://code.qt.io/cgit). I entered a message "qmake" in a search field. And I got a message "No repositories found".

Is QMake open source?

Comment: https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/qmake

Answer (score 7):

[qmake](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-manual.html) source is in [qtbase](https://github.com/qt/qtbase) tree, for example here on github [official Qt repository mirror](https://github.com/qt) -> https://github.com/qt/qtbase/tree/5.10/qmake

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to build the Vulkan SDK from source, and the VulkanCapsViewer repository in the Vulkan SDK requires **qmake**. (It gave the error: `qmake: command not found`)

I tried to build qmake only, and this was successful, but the VulkanCapsViewer requires a few other QT modules too (core network widgets gui) that I ended up not building.

Although the [qtbase](https://github.com/qt/qtbase) repository contains a lot of code, it's possible to turn off most of the features and only build **qmake**.

The configure script in `qtbase` can give a list of all features with the command:

```
./configure -list-features
```

I used the following config options to build only **qmake** and almost nothing else. I still had to edit 1-2 source files to get it to compile (by commenting out some parts). The features required for **qmake** and the Vulkan SDK are enabled at the end of the list.

*(This list contains some duplicates, I may edit the duplicates out later)*

```
./configure --prefix=`pwd`/../qtbase_bin \
    -make tools \
    -submodules core \
    -no-gui \
    -no-widgets \
    -no-dbus \
    -no-accessibility \
    -no-slog2 \
    -no-ssl \
    -no-cups \
    -no-fontconfig \
    -no-freetype \
    -no-harfbuzz \
    -no-gtk \
    -no-opengl \
    -no-opengles3 \
    -no-egl \
    -no-qpa \
    -no-xcb-xlib \
    -no-direct2d \
    -no-directfb \
    -no-eglfs \
    -no-gbm \
    -no-linuxfb \
    -no-xcb \
    -no-libudev \
    -no-evdev \
    -no-libinput \
    -no-mtdev \
    -no-tslib \
    -no-bundled-xcb-xinput \
    -no-xkbcommon \
    -no-unity-build \
    \
    -nomake tools -nomake examples -nomake tests -skip qt3d -skip qtandroidextras -skip qtcanvas3d -skip qtcharts -skip qtconnectivity -skip qtdatavis3d -skip qtdeclarative -skip qtdoc -skip qtgamepad -skip qtgraphicaleffects -skip qtimageformats -skip qtlocation -skip qtmacextras -skip qtmultimedia -skip qtnetworkauth -skip qtpurchasing -skip qtquickcontrols -skip qtquickcontrols2 -skip qtscript -skip qtscxml -skip qtsensors -skip qtserialbus -skip qtserialport -skip qtspeech -skip qtsvg -skip qttools -skip qttranslations -skip qtvirtualkeyboard -skip qtwayland -skip qtwebchannel -skip qtwebengine -skip qtwebsockets -skip qtwebview -skip qtwinextras -skip qtx11extras -skip qtxmlpatterns -no-feature-texthtmlparser -no-feature-textodfwriter -no-feature-concurrent -no-feature-effects -no-feature-sharedmemory -no-feature-systemsemaphore -no-feature-im -no-feature-process -no-feature-dom -no-feature-filesystemmodel -no-feature-filesystemwatcher -no-feature-graphicsview -no-feature-graphicseffect -no-feature-sizegrip -no-feature-calendarwidget -no-feature-printpreviewwidget -no-feature-keysequenceedit -no-feature-colordialog -no-feature-filedialog -no-feature-fontdialog -no-feature-printpreviewdialog -no-feature-progressdialog -no-feature-inputdialog -no-feature-errormessage -no-feature-wizard -no-feature-datawidgetmapper -no-feature-imageformat_bmp -no-feature-imageformat_ppm -no-feature-imageformat_xbm -no-feature-imageformat_png -no-feature-imageformat_jpeg -no-feature-image_heuristic_mask -no-feature-image_text -no-feature-colornames -no-feature-cups -no-feature-freetype -no-feature-translation -no-feature-udpsocket -no-feature-networkproxy -no-feature-socks5 -no-feature-networkdiskcache -no-feature-completer -no-feature-fscompleter -no-feature-desktopservices -no-feature-mimetype -no-feature-systemtrayicon -no-feature-undocommand -no-feature-undostack -no-feature-undogroup -no-feature-undoview -no-feature-gestures -no-feature-dbus \
    -no-feature-abstractbutton \
    -no-feature-abstractslider \
    -no-feature-accessibility \
    -no-feature-action \
    -no-feature-androiddeployqt \
    -no-feature-animation \
    -no-feature-appstore-compliant \
    -no-feature-batch_test_support \
    -no-feature-brotli \
    -no-feature-buttongroup \
    -no-feature-calendarwidget \
    -no-feature-checkbox \
    -no-feature-clipboard \
    -no-feature-colordialog \
    -no-feature-colornames \
    -no-feature-columnview \
    -no-feature-combobox \
    -no-feature-commandlinkbutton \
    -no-feature-completer \
    -no-feature-concatenatetablesproxymodel \
    -no-feature-concurrent \
    -no-feature-contextmenu \
    -no-feature-cpp-winrt \
    -no-feature-cssparser \
    -no-feature-cups \
    -no-feature-cursor \
    -no-feature-datawidgetmapper \
    -no-feature-datetimeedit \
    -no-feature-datetimeparser \
    -no-feature-desktopservices \
    -no-feature-dial \
    -no-feature-dialog \
    -no-feature-dialogbuttonbox \
    -no-feature-dnslookup \
    -no-feature-dockwidget \
    -no-feature-dom \
    -no-feature-draganddrop \
    -no-feature-dtls \
    -no-feature-easingcurve \
    -no-feature-effects \
    -no-feature-errormessage \
    -no-feature-filedialog \
    -no-feature-filesystemmodel \
    -no-feature-filesystemwatcher \
    -no-feature-fontcombobox \
    -no-feature-fontdialog \
    -no-feature-formlayout \
    -no-feature-freetype \
    -no-feature-fscompleter \
    -no-feature-future \
    -no-feature-gestures \
    -no-feature-graphicseffect \
    -no-feature-graphicsframecapture \
    -no-feature-graphicsview \
    -no-feature-groupbox \
    -no-feature-gssapi \
    -no-feature-highdpiscaling \
    -no-feature-hijricalendar \
    -no-feature-http \
    -no-feature-identityproxymodel \
    -no-feature-im \
    -no-feature-image_heuristic_mask \
    -no-feature-image_text \
    -no-feature-imageformat_bmp \
    -no-feature-imageformat_jpeg \
    -no-feature-imageformat_png \
    -no-feature-imageformat_ppm \
    -no-feature-imageformat_xbm \
    -no-feature-imageformat_xpm \
    -no-feature-imageformatplugin \
    -no-feature-inputdialog \
    -no-feature-islamiccivilcalendar \
    -no-feature-itemmodel \
    -no-feature-itemmodeltester \
    -no-feature-itemviews \
    -no-feature-jalalicalendar \
    -no-feature-keysequenceedit \
    -no-feature-label \
    -no-feature-lcdnumber \
    -no-feature-library \
    -no-feature-lineedit \
    -no-feature-listview \
    -no-feature-listwidget \
    -no-feature-localserver \
    -no-feature-macdeployqt \
    -no-feature-mainwindow \
    -no-feature-mdiarea \
    -no-feature-menu \
    -no-feature-menubar \
    -no-feature-messagebox \
    -no-feature-mimetype \
    -no-feature-movie \
    -no-feature-multiprocess \
    -no-feature-networkdiskcache \
    -no-feature-networkinterface \
    -no-feature-networklistmanager \
    -no-feature-networkproxy \
    -no-feature-ocsp \
    -no-feature-openssl-hash \
    -no-feature-pdf \
    -no-feature-permissions \
    -no-feature-picture \
    -no-feature-poll-exit-on-error \
    -no-feature-printdialog \
    -no-feature-printer \
    -no-feature-printpreviewdialog \
    -no-feature-printpreviewwidget \
    -no-feature-process \
    -no-feature-processenvironment \
    -no-feature-progressbar \
    -no-feature-progressdialog \
    -no-feature-proxymodel \
    -no-feature-pushbutton \
    -no-feature-radiobutton \
    -no-feature-raster-64bit \
    -no-feature-raster-fp \
    -no-feature-relocatable \
    -no-feature-resizehandler \
    -no-feature-rubberband \
    -no-feature-sanitize_fuzzer_no_link \
    -no-feature-scrollarea \
    -no-feature-scrollbar \
    -no-feature-scroller \
    -no-feature-sessionmanager \
    -no-feature-sha3-fast \
    -no-feature-sharedmemory \
    -no-feature-shortcut \
    -no-feature-sizegrip \
    -no-feature-slider \
    -no-feature-socks5 \
    -no-feature-sortfilterproxymodel \
    -no-feature-spinbox \
    -no-feature-splashscreen \
    -no-feature-splitter \
    -no-feature-sqlmodel \
    -no-feature-sspi \
    -no-feature-stackedwidget \
    -no-feature-standarditemmodel \
    -no-feature-statusbar \
    -no-feature-statustip \
    -no-feature-stringlistmodel \
    -no-feature-style-stylesheet \
    -no-feature-syntaxhighlighter \
    -no-feature-systemsemaphore \
    -no-feature-systemtrayicon \
    -no-feature-tabbar \
    -no-feature-tabletevent \
    -no-feature-tableview \
    -no-feature-tablewidget \
    -no-feature-tabwidget \
    -no-feature-testlib_selfcover \
    -no-feature-textbrowser \
    -no-feature-textedit \
    -no-feature-texthtmlparser \
    -no-feature-textmarkdownreader \
    -no-feature-textmarkdownwriter \
    -no-feature-textodfwriter \
    -no-feature-thread \
    -no-feature-timezone \
    -no-feature-toolbar \
    -no-feature-toolbox \
    -no-feature-toolbutton \
    -no-feature-tooltip \
    -no-feature-topleveldomain \
    -no-feature-translation \
    -no-feature-transposeproxymodel \
    -no-feature-treeview \
    -no-feature-treewidget \
    -no-feature-tuiotouch \
    -no-feature-udpsocket \
    -no-feature-undocommand \
    -no-feature-undogroup \
    -no-feature-undostack \
    -no-feature-undoview \
    -no-feature-valgrind \
    -no-feature-validator \
    -no-feature-wasm-exceptions \
    -no-feature-wasm-simd128 \
    -no-feature-whatsthis \
    -no-feature-wheelevent \
    -no-feature-widgettextcontrol \
    -no-feature-windeployqt \
    -no-feature-wizard \
    \
    \
        `# needed for qmake` \
    -feature-qmake \
    -feature-regularexpression \
    -feature-settings \
    -feature-temporaryfile \
    -feature-datestring \
    -feature-textdate \
    -feature-cborstreamreader \
    -feature-cborstreamwriter \
    \
    \
        `# some of the code fails to compile without this` \
    -feature-commandlineparser \
    -feature-xmlstream \
    -feature-xmlstreamreader \
    -feature-xmlstreamwriter \
    \
    \
        `# needed by Vulkan SDK / VulkanCapsViewer` \
    \
    -feature-filesystemiterator \
    \
    \
        `# recommended by the configure script` \
    -DQT_NO_FEATURE_AUTO_RESET=ON \
```

I also needed to add the QMAKESPEC environment variable to point to the `mkspecs/linux-g++` folder that contains the `qmake.conf` file, to make it work with the VulkanCapsViewer build script.

```
export QMAKESPEC=/PATH_TO/qtbase_bin/mkspecs/linux-g++
```

This was successful, but I needed to enable a few more QT modules (core network widgets gui) to build the VulkanCapsViewer repository, and it was easier at that point to disable building the VulkanCapsViewer reqpository instead (by commenting it out in the `vulkansdk` script).

Also thanks to these other answers:

https://forum.qt.io/topic/17668/qmake-does-not-seem-to-recognize-linux-g-specification-on-opensuse-12-1

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13257311/812973